# How to sort a string x by the order in which they appear in string y?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a method `sort_by_letter` that takes two string arguments and sorts the first by each letter in the order they appear in the second string.

```
x = "cat"
y = "kndttayc"

sort_by_letter(x, y) 
  #=> "tac"
```

Comment: Since your example shows duplicate letters in `y` but not in `x`: if you passed `sort_by_letter('dcaaeb', 'abcade')` would you expect `'abcade'`, `'aabcde'`, or `'bcaade'`?

Comment: what happens if a letter is not in `y` at all does this get placed at the end or the beginning? eg. `x = "cats"; sort_by_letter(x, y)` would be `"tacs"` or `"stac"`?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
x.each_char.sort_by { |str| y.index str }.join
```

Comment: ah that worked perfectly! I was creating variables by creating calling .chars on each string and iterating over the both of them, then ...a lot less elegant than yours ;)

Comment: You can omit the `''` argument to `join`. `x.each_char.sort_by{|str| y.index str}.join`

Answer (score 3):

Subush's answer is straightforward, and works fine, but if the strings become long, and you want to care about efficiency, you might also want to do this:

```
h = y.each_char.with_index.to_h
#=> {"k"=>0, "n"=>1, "d"=>2, "t"=>4, "a"=>5, "y"=>6, "c"=>7}
x.each_char.sort_by{|c| h[c]}.join
#=> "tac"
```

Note: See Simple Lime's comment to the question. Subush's answer and my answer are respectively correct under different interpretation regarding this point.

Comment: This solution has a glitch: the last index wins, while you obviously want the first to win. Reverse the input string upfront and `zip` to `length.downto(1)` instead of `with_index`.

Comment: @mudasobwa "while you obviously want the first to win"-- Where does that come from? See my last sentence in the answer.

Comment: `y = "tatc"` should return `"tac"`, no? [Well, maybe I am wrong, and if not, `y.split('').uniq.join` would do better than zipping to reversed range].

Comment: @mudasobwa The OP hasn't made clear whether it should return `"tac"` or `"atc"`.

Comment: @mudasobwa in that case `y.chars.&(x.chars).join`